# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable This is a program computing different number of outcomes in a 6 digit password

Tags: python-3.x

```
pass_length = 26
for i in range(1,7):
    total_length = int(pass_length ** i)
    print(total_length)

print(sum(total_length))
```

This is a program computing a different number of outcomes in a 6 digit password. Please help me understand my error!

Comment: I guess you should wirte like following://pass_length = 26
total_length = 0
for i in range(1,7):
    total_length += int(pass_length ** i)
    print(total_length)

Answer (score 0):

In your program, `total_length` gets reassigned to an `int` each iteration of the loop, whereas `sum` expects an `iterable`, such as a list, for the first argument. You would have to generate a list using your loop to be able to pass it to the `sum` function:

```
pass_length = 26
total_length = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    total_length.append(int(pass_length ** i))

print(sum(total_length))
```

The loop can be simplified using list comprehension:

```
pass_length = 26
print(sum([int(pass_length ** i) for i in range(1, 7)]))
```

or to be even more efficient, using a generator:

```
pass_length = 26
print(sum(int(pass_length ** i) for i in range(1, 7)))
```